# Do I need to take both particles' momentum into account in photoelectric emission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

> An aluminum dust particle of mass $m=2.2*10^{-18}$ grams is floating in space ( initial velocity is zero). The particle emits electron under influence of a photon whose frequency is $8*10^{17}$ hertz. If the work function of aluminum is $W=4.08$ electron volts, calculate the speed of the particle after the emission.. Velocity vectors of particle and photon have same but respectively negative directions.

My attempt:
Calculate velocity of electron by using Einstein's photoelectric effect equation. Use conservation of momentum to calculate the speed of the particle. What puzzles me is: Do I need to take both electron and photon momentum into calculations??

Maybe conservation of energy would be a better approach??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method outlined will work. You can get a good approximation by ignoring the photon because the photon has a lot less momentum than the electron ejected.